# F# Print if true

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to print the output of function only when it is true but so far all attempts have been unsuccsessful.

Something on the lines of:

```
let printFactor a b =  if b then print_any((a,b))
```

Where `b` is a boolean and `a` is an integer. 
When I try it I get:

```
val printFactor : 'a -> bool -> unit
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

To put things in context im trying to use this with a pipe operator. Lets say I have a function `xyz` that outputs a list of (int, bool). Id like to do something on these lines:

```
xyz |> printFactor
```

to print the true values only.

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking or what you are trying to do.

Comment: that is the correct type signature for the function you wrote. what is the function `print_any` do? look there next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do e.g. this

```
let xyz() = [ (1,true); (2,false) ]

let printFactor (i,b) = 
    if b then
        printfn "%A" i

xyz() |> List.iter printFactor
```

but it would probably be more idiomatic to do, e.g. this

```
xyz() 
|> List.filter (fun (i,b) -> b) 
|> List.iter (fun (i,b) -> printfn "%d" i)
```

that is, first filter, and then print.